# Error al utilizar JOptionPane

Tags: java, joptionpane

Buenas tardes querida comunidad, soy nuevo en Java, alguien podria ayudarme con un error que me marca al utilizar JOptionPane por favor? a continuación adjunto screen.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Creo que falta importarlo, siempre fíjate en las sugerencias que te da el editor, o sea dale clic al bombillo amarillo del lado izquierdo, probablemente te diga que necesites importar

Comment: Hola David, "click" derecho en algún espacio vacío, "Fix imports" y boileeau!!!